# StreamBuilder not updating Firestore data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I'm making a Flutter application and I'm trying to get the user's data in the app.

So basically, the user registers with his info (name, email, password), and this data is displayed in a `ProfilePage` when he's logged in.

According to Firestore documentation, I'm supposed to use a `StreamBuilder` to get his data.

At this point, everything works fine.

The problem is that when the user logs out and another user logs in, the `ProfilePage` displays the precedent user's data (the user logged out).

Only if I restart the app, then I'm getting the right data.

Here's my `ProfilePage` :

```
class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
}

class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {

  final _uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection('UserData')
        .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       key: Key(_uid),
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['full_name']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['company']),
                );
              })
              .toList()
              .cast(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I see that this is a question asked several times on SO but I couldn't find a good solution. I tried to add a unique key in the `StreamBuilder` but it doesn't solve the problem.

I also saw the use of `didUpdateWidget` but I don't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this:

```
  final _uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

with this:

```
  late final _uid;
  @override
  initState() {
  _uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  super.initState();
 }
```

then restart your app again, and simulate your behavior

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it's not working. The data updates only if I restart the app.

Comment: check the other possible solution

Answer (score 0):

reload the current user details with:

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.reload();
```

I will say that the best place to put it, is to do it before returning that stream, first make the Stream a method:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> myStream() async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.reload();
final _uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
    .doc(_uid)
    .collection('UserData')
    .snapshots();
}
```

then in the `StreamBuilder`, set `stream` property to:

```
stream: myStream(),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

I simply moved the stream inside the build and the problem is solved !

After edit :

````
class UserInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserInformationState createState() => _UserInformationState();
}

class _UserInformationState extends State<UserInformation> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 final _uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users')
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection('UserData')
        .snapshots();

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       key: Key(_uid),
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Text("Loading");
        }

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(data['full_name']),
                  subtitle: Text(data['company']),
                );
              })
              .toList()
              .cast(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```
````